Handling Specific Exceptions in WebClient Calls in Client using Spring WebFlux
How to catch specific exception thrown by server in client service when using webclient to communicate?
Let me explain a use case -
I have a service A.
Now A has a method (callExternalApi) which is calling an external service B using webclient-

public <T> T callExternalApi(String uri, Class<T> responseType) throws DatabaseFetchException{
        try {
            return webClient.get().uri(uri).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).retrieve().bodyToMono(responseType).block();
        }catch(DatabaseFetchException e ){
            System.out.println("Database Exception occurred");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Generic Exception occurred");
        }
        return null;
    }


Now lets say the endpoint uri in B which is being called by A is "/info"-
@GetMapping(value = "/info")
    public InfoDTO getInfoForA(@PathVariable @NonNull String id) throws DatabaseFetchException {
        InfoDTO infoDTO = DBService.getInfoById(id);
        return infoDTO;
    }

Now issue here is, when B is actually throwing a DatabaseFetchException, A is not getting that specific exception, rather it keeps going to the last catch block i.e. -
catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Generic Exception occurred");
        }


What am I missing here. Please help!

If we print exception in callExternalApi, like e.printStackTrace(), what will we get? Obviously we did not get DatabaseFetchException, in such case it will be printed, but what the exception we got really?

Is service B on another application or it is running in the same app as Service A? In both cases, the webclient won't capture those specific execeptions from service B, it will get a web client exception with the error/status code received from service b. If you need to make service B return error responses that you can easily interpret in service A, you will need to have some sort of ControllerAdvice in service B and return a response that you can then process in service A

Ok. Do you have any sample code for this ?
